# Cargar titulo de evento almacenado en mysql en calendario

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

tengo un problema con mi codigo. Tengo un calendario programado en php que encontré en la web y logre hacer que guarde eventos, ahora quiero poder mostrar el titulo del evento en el recuadro del día si es que existe pero no logro hacerlo.

la tabla mysql es eventos y tiene los siguientes campos: id | titulo | fecha | hora

el codigo php es el siguiente:

`<?php

include './php/conexion.php';


// Set your timezone!!
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
setlocale(LC_TIME, "spanish");


// Get prev & next month
if (isset($_GET['ym'])) {
    $ym = $_GET['ym'];
} else {
    // This month
    $ym = date('Y-m');
}

// Check format
$timestamp = strtotime($ym . '-01');  // the first day of the month
if ($timestamp === false) {
    $ym = date('Y-m');
    $timestamp = strtotime($ym . '-01');
}

// Today (Format:2018-08-8)
$today = date('Y-m-j');

// Title (Format:August, 2018)
$title = date('F, Y', $timestamp);
$titulo = strftime("%B del %Y", strtotime($title));

// Create prev & next month link
$prev = date('Y-m', strtotime('-1 month', $timestamp));
$next = date('Y-m', strtotime('+1 month', $timestamp));

// Number of days in the month
$day_count = date('t', $timestamp);

// 1:Mon 2:Tue 3: Wed ... 7:Sun
$str = date('N', $timestamp);

// Array for calendar
$weeks = [];
$week = '';

// Add empty cell(s)
$week .= str_repeat('<td></td>', $str - 1);

for ($day = 01; $day <= $day_count; $day++, $str++) {

    $date = $ym . '-' .$day;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE fecha = $day";
    $ejecutarQuery = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
    $eventos = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutarQuery);

    if($ejecutarQuery->num_rows > 0){
      echo $eventos['title'];
     }else{
      echo "error";
     };
    

    if ($today == $date) {
        $week .= "<td class='today' onClick='f(this)' id=".$date.">";
    } else {
        $week .= "<td onClick='f(this)' id=".$date.">";
    }
    $week .= $day . '</td>';

    // Sunday OR last day of the month
    if ($str % 7 == 0 || $day == $day_count) {

        // last day of the month
        if ($day == $day_count && $str % 7 != 0) {
            // Add empty cell(s)
            $week .= str_repeat('<td></td>', 7 - $str % 7);
        }

        $weeks[] = '<tr>' . $week . '</tr>';

        $week = '';
    }
}

?>`

PD: intente realizar una consulta a mysql en el for que se encarga de imprimir los  que muestran los dias consultando que la el campo fecha de mi tabla sea igual a la variable $date pero no me devuelve nunca nada.

Comment: No he entendido cuál es el problema, ¿la consulta no devuelve datos? Si es eso revisa la conexión, la consulta, y verifica que realmente hay datos con esos criterios.

Comment: @A.Cedano Hola, la consulta si devuelve datos pero yo quiero que dentro del for, donde se crea el <td> que muestra el numero del dia tambien muestre el titulo del evento, o en su defecto algun punto, pero al hacer la consulta mysql con el parametro "WHERE fecha = $date" no devuelve nada, si yo quito el $date y selecciono todo lo que tiene la variable puedo tener acceso al arreglo con lo que haya en la tabla...

Comment: Otra vez no queda claro: ¿devuelve datos o no devuelve datos? ¿devuelve datos si no le pones el WHERE y no devuelve si le pones el WHERE? No sé por qué la gente se lía tanto para explicar un problema. Entonces, pregunto de nuevo: ¿el problema cuál es?

Comment: @A.Cedano Si le pongo el where no devuelve, si se lo saco si. El problema es que no puedo obtener los eventos que correspondan a ese dia.

Comment: Ya, pero ¿verificaste que la variable cuando pones el `WHERE` es válida? ¿Verificaste si la tabla tiene filas que cumplen esos criterios? Puedes por ejemplo imprimir la consulta para revisarla/ejecutarla directamente en el SGBD para ver si realmente hay filas con esos criterios.

Comment: @A.Cedano Al principio creí que eso era el problema ya que mi campo fecha era tipo date y no almacenaba lo mismo que la variable $date, por lo que decidí cambiarla a varchar y siguió sin funcionar :(

Comment: Es un error cambiar una columna del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME` a `VARCHAR`. Si algo no funcionaba debes verificar lo que no funciona y resolverlo, no cambiar a un tipo de dato que nada tiene que ver con lo que se quiere almacenar. Sea como sea, tampoco veo ninguna consulta SQL en el código que has compartido. Y, si estás empezando con la tabla, sugiero que vuelvas a declarar la columna del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME` y que pongas los datos bien, con el formato `AÑO-MES-DIA`, por ejemplo: `2020-03-15` para el 15 de marzo de 2020.  Y para comparar tienes que pasar la cadena fecha en ese mismo formato

Comment: Claro, el problema es que el día de la fecha se almacena mediante un for, el cual empieza en 1 y no en 01 como almacena la tabla, entonces por ese motivo decidí cambiarlo a varchar y que sea un string. Voy a editar la pregunta para que puedas ver como ejecuto la consulta :)

Comment: Como ya dije, eso no justifica que cambies el tipo de dato en la BD. El problema de hacer eso es que te expones a errores y que cuando necesites hacer comparaciones o generar datos estadísticos, vas a tener que convertir ese VARCHAR a DATE, exponiéndote a más errores y sobrecargando el código. Si recibes los días con cifras sin cero, las funciones y clases de fecha en PHP tienen tipos de formato para crear fechas con los valores así y si no PHP tiene funciones para agregar fácilmente un cero o los ceros que quieras a la izquierda de los valores.

Comment: NO te aconsejo que sigas por ese camino. Corrige tu base de datos, y luego intenta construir las fechas válidas usando los formatos propios de PHP. Si tienes problemas en ese punto aquí estamos para ayudarte. Lo que aquí ocurre es que estás trasladando un problema que debe resolverse por código PHP a la base de datos y eso es gravísimo, porque estás diseñando mal la BD intentando resolver un problema que es contextual (en PHP) y que debes resolver en PHP.